# Must declare the scalar variable (SQL)

Tags: sql, vb.net

Please help me with this problem, I've been searching couple hours and can't solve it.

Here is my code :

```vb
Private Sub search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles search_btn.Click
    connectionString = "Data Source=MININT-BJDM4MI;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\QCDB.mdf;Database=QCDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE SAMPLE_SOURCE = @SOURCE"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOURCE", spl_source_combox.Text)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "PRODUCT")
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the SqlDataAdapter, you should be passing in your command object instead of the SQL string.

```
Private Sub search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles search_btn.Click
connectionString = "Data Source=MININT-BJDM4MI;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\QCDB.mdf;Database=QCDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE SAMPLE_SOURCE = @SOURCE"

Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOURCE", spl_source_combox.Text)

Try
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "PRODUCT")
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be even better though if you used a stored procedure rather than to pass sql in your code, but the reason for your exception is because the @SOURCE variable isn't declared in your SQL statement. Try this:

`sql = "DECLARE @SOURCE varchar(50);SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE SAMPLE_SOURCE = @SOURCE"`

Comment: This doesn't solve. Variable needs to be set in vb code.

Comment: Yeah, the variable is set in vb code, but it's declared in the SQL code

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to your @source: Use this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOURCE", spl_source_combox.Text) = "<Your Value>"
```